# jquery load not work in firefox and ie

Tags: jquery

my code is here

```
<a href="javascript:
       $( '.page-content' ).load( 'jsp/content/company.jsp', function() {
            App.init();TableEditable.init();UITree.init();
            });
  " >something here</a>
```

I would like to replace one part of part by the other page. I wroked on chown, but not worked on firefox and ie. Is there another solution ? thank you.

Comment: looks like you have a multiline attribute value, might be because of that... is there any error in your browser console

Answer (score 0):

Give your anchor a class to target it more accurate:

```
<a href="#" class="link">something here</a>
```

Then instead of inline javascript, try to use `.click()` instead:

```
$('a.link').click(function() {
    $( '.page-content' ).load( 'jsp/content/company.jsp', function() {
        App.init();
        TableEditable.init();
        UITree.init();
    });
});
```